# SOAP with external namepaces deserializes to NULL

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm implementing a client to a SOAP-service, which I don't have access to. Since I'm a bit of a newcomer, I really don't have much experience with SOAP, so I went with the default approach of adding the Service Reference via Visual Studio 2017, configuring the Service via config-file and then hope it works.
Unfortunately, whenever I call the service, I get a NULL-response. Searching a bit, it seems like some Namespace problems. In fact, the WSDL has a lot of defined external namespaces, like:

`xmlns:eCH-0011="http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0011-f/8"`

I thought, the proxy generator would take of this, but for example when I use the http://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/, I get a namespace exception like:

> Schema parsing error In diesem Schema ist Namespace
>   'http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0044-f/4' nicht für den Verweis
>   verfügbar.

Which is german and means the namespce is not avaliable for a reference.

I tried to create the WSDL dynamically by calling the service with the "svc?wsdl" prefix as well as received a WSDL from the developers, but both are not working.
I also used Fiddler as proxy, and I see in the response I would get correct XML, but yet, in the code I don't get any error nor other feedback what the problem is.

Is it generally not possible to have external namespaces, or am I configuring something wrong here? I'm currently trying to kindahow sneak between the incomming data and the deserialization, but didn't have any luck so far. Sadly, there are not much information around as far as I seached for it.

Playing around: I played around further, implementing a IClientMessageInspector and a IEndpointBehavior, where I can debug the incoming message. This seems fine, so it has to be the SOAP-formatter, which causes problems here. Unfortunately, I still can't get an Exception, yet it's always null.

Comment: You can always make a standard http request for `application/xml` and parse the xml manually if it comes to that.

Comment: Thanks, I added a inspector, and I get the SOAP with the namespaces. My question: Is the handling of these namespaces a problem of the server, or do I as a client have to handle that?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem if you manually parse the xml (unless the namespaces change without notice). I have a feeling the SOAP service is not compatible with .Net proxy generator. I have had the painful experience of integrating with a Java service and had to resort to raw xml.

Comment: Thanks, I am in fact trying to parse it manually now. Unfortunately, I'm now getting the dreaded "xmlns='' was not expected" error..

Comment: maybe the xml is malformed. Is this an otherwise reliable service as far as you know?

Comment: @Crowcoder manually code XML is a desperate attempt at  best. Is there any way we could view the WSDL?